# How to set up android emulator for live face detection?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, face-detection

I have an emulator running 4.1 Android. Virtual device is set up so that it has camera emulated by the web cam. This part works fine.

However `Camera.Parameters.getMaxNumDetectedFaces()` always returns 0, meaning that face detection is not supported (though it works fine on static images).

Is there anything that can be done in order to enable live face detection on Android emulator? I am talking about the face detection that came with API level 14, not third party libraries.

Thanks, Viktor.

Comment: Many parts of the emulator do not work right for hardware emulation. I would guess as this is a newer feature, you wont have much luck. Honestly never even got my own web cam working properly or the fake GPS values, etc.

Comment: Yeah, if they could do live face detection in software for the emulator, they could release a compat library to do live face detection on older Android devices that don't have hardware support too.  I'd love to see that happen, but I don't think it's likely.

Answer (score 2):

No. Unfortunately, the API 14 face detection requires hardware support.

Comment: He's using API 14 as he mention android 4.1 which is API level 15

Comment: There are two face detection APIs in Android, one that's been in the code since API 0 and one added in API 14. I'm talking about the face detection added in API 14 which includes the getMaxNumDetectedFaces() function.

Comment: I think there is not face detection API from API 0.There is only one api and that is after API 14.  Can you give a reference for FaceDetection API for API 0